# Show alert if moving on without saving in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, events, navigation

**Functionnaly :**
On one of my components of my application, I have an editing/lock system. When a user starts editing, he locks the file so other users cannot edit it.

**Problem scenario** : When the user activates "edition mode" and leaves screen, I would like to show a alert with two options : save changes, or discard changes.

There are different ways to exit screen :

- There is a List on the left side containing other possible editabel data. A click changes the data in my component.
- There is a menubar on top leading to other screens.
- The edition component is embedded in a Tab navigator. When changing tabs, the alert has to show.
- Closing browser.

Do I have to catch all of these events and plug at all those places? 
Is there any kind of *focusout* mecanism?

Comment: I strongly doubt you can catch the browser closing or anything like that (I hope!).

Comment: @Lo'oris you actually can catch the browser attempting to close with JavaScript. If you don't believe me, try closing GMAIL or Google Docs while editing something before saving. Using external interface you could in theory catch the user before closing the browser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to the first question is: YES.

You need to watch all possible exit events that could harm the currently edited data.

Well, the problem is now how to manage this properly. Using an MVC framework you would trigger the appropriate commands from your components:

- CHANGE_LIST_ITEM (new item)
- CHANGE_TAB (new tab)
- CHANGE_SCREEN (new screen)

Each command then checks if the currently edited tab has been saved or not. If not, it displays the Alert. Else, if there are no changes, it allows the list, the screen chooser and the tab bar to continue.

So your components (list, screens, tabs) need to implement some kind of rollback or preventDefault mechanism. Generally, changing their state must be allowed by a central validator (in MVC the command).

In the case of the list: I would suggest that the list is not selectable by mouse click but only programmatically. You set a listener on the list item click event. If the command allows setting of a new item it will notify the list. In MVC usually by sending an async message that gets received by the list's mediator. [[And even more correct: The command would set some model properties (e.g. currentListItem) and the model than sends an async message.]]

Edit: For the browser close event, you need to call a JavaScript expert.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But badly enough, no MVC framework was used and this is going to be a awfull job plugging the alert... I'll keep the question open for a couple of days to see if any else has an other point of view.

Comment: My current job is exactly the same: editable tab, screens, list and the alert (save, discard) but not the browser thing :D However, its almost finished.

Comment: @Zenklys Jens answer is just about spot on. For a similar requirement here, I catch all navigation events (I'm using the Mate framework) and check to see if the user has saved their work. If not, I dispatch the save prompt.

Comment: I agree with this answer as well. One thing I've done in the past, when I can get away with it, is to make my forms in a modal popup. This of course has other implications on usability, but it severely limits the exit points to the forms. Having a proper framework such as RobotLegs, MATE, or Parsely is immensely helpful with such tasks.

Comment: Interesting conception the modal popup Jonathan. I'll give it a try.